# How to set limit on input from 0-100 Java

Tags: java

So this is my code: I need to set a limit on the input of the grades in the switch statement so that it will not go over 100 and under 0. If anyone could help, that would be incredible. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class assigment1{

static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args){
     int number;

     System.out.println("Student Grade System");
     System.out.println("====================");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("   1) Enter student details");
     System.out.println("   2) Dsiplay student grades");
     System.out.println("   3) Display student statistics");
     System.out.println("   4) Display full transcript");
     System.out.println("   0)Exit system");
     System.out.println("   ");
     System.out.print("Select an option [0-4]>>");

     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
     number=input.nextInt();

      switch(number){
        case 1:
          System.out.print("Entering Student Detials");
          System.out.print("========================");
          System.out.print("    Student number:                ");String a =key.nextLine();
          System.out.print("    Programing Grade:              ");number=input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("    web Development Grade:         ");number=input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("    Mathematics Grade:             ");number=input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("    Critical Thinking Grade:       ");number=input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("    Operating System Grade:        ");number=input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("    Computer Archetecture Grade:   ");number=input.nextInt();
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("Display stuent grades");
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("Display student statistics");
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("Display full transcript");
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Thanks for using the system");
          break;
```

Comment: how would you type it in english?. i.e: if number larger than 100 or smaller than or equal to 0, quit...

Comment: Its not clear at all. You are talking about which grade?there are 5-6 types of grade in your code

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function like this:

(didn't tried this code)

```
private int getNumberFrom0To100() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result;
    do {
        result = in.nextInt();
    } while(result < 0 || result > 100);
    return result;
}
```

and use it at your needed position:

```
number = getNumberFrom0To100();
```

Else have a look at the delimiter function where you can pass regex:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("^[1]?[0-9]?[0-9]$");
```

Comment: Do not forget the "do" in your "do...while"

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code , You must write This code Before Switch Case :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter The number");
int score = in.nextInt();
while(score<0||score>100){
     System.out.println("You Entered the wrong number , Enter The number Again :");
     score = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner to fit in your code's logic and display

### Solution

```
while((number = Math.abs(input.nextInt())) > 100) 
System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again");
```

---

### Console

```
537
Invalid input. Try Again
-537
Invalid input. Try Again
-2
```

---

### Attention

If user enters `-2` for example, it will take it as a valid input since `2` which is `abs(-2)` is contained between 0 and 100.

Comment: So why give a solution that doesn't do what the OP requested (0-100) when checking `number < 0 || number > 100` is simple, and does not require any method calls or conversions to double?

Comment: @RealSkeptic This works also with the only difference that it takes the absolute number. Which is logic for a grade. But you make sense.